# How do I recover over 900 discarded items and over 200 transferred Pokemon

Tags: pokemon-go

My ex girlfriend deleted over 900 items and over 200 of my top Pokemon. Is there any way I can recover them?

Comment: Am I a bad person for calling BS? The inventory limit is 350 by default, and while you can exceed it by buying items or levelling up, to have "over 900" you have to have spent at least $30-$40 on the game just for PokéBalls (which you get for free from active gameplay). Makes me feel unsurprised that your "ex girlfriend" decided to teach you a lesson in this way. Learn from the experience...

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol You're not. My biggest gripe is why did your ex gf have enough time to discard 900 items and transfer 200 Pokemon. Why does she have your phone? There's also the wild possibility he deserved it ;-)

Comment: You can buy bag upgrades to increase your storage capacity, up to a max of 1000. I assume the OP had upgraded his bag.

Answer (score 3):

You would have to submit a support ticket to Niantic, and hope they are willing and able to roll back your account or restore the items.

Niantic's support system does not allow you to submit requests regarding hacked* accounts. You would have to use either their [premium item issue](https://support.pokemongo.nianticlabs.com/hc/en-us/requests/new?ticket_form_id=320008) or [login issue](https://support.pokemongo.nianticlabs.com/hc/en-us/requests/new?ticket_form_id=265607) form and hope it finds its way to someone who can and will help.

Don't count on it though- Niantic's customer support was bad enough before it became overloaded by Pokemon Go. Assume the items and pokemon aren't coming back.

Let this be a lesson- don't let other people use your account.

- For purposes of this question, "hacked" refers to any unauthorised access. Even if in this case you let her use the account.

Comment: Both of those forms are inappropriate ways to contact Niantic about this issue. (I didn't downvote)

Comment: @JAL As I said in the answer, there is no official way to contact about this issue. Unless you're saying you know of one that you simply didn't bother to add to your answer?

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to recover discarded items or Pokemon transferred to the professor.

Comment: Not even by Pokemon go

Comment: No, Niantic will not reverse transfers or discarded items.  See their support article: https://support.pokemongo.nianticlabs.com/hc/en-us/articles/222049867-Viewing-a-Pokémon-s-Summary-

Comment: @JAL I'm not convinced that article covers this. It's pretty clear this refers to normal use- not unauthorised access.

Comment: @Studoku Niantic will not consider an ex-girlfriend "unauthorized access."  Niantic will not restore the items and Pokemon.  Source: emails with Niantic support

Comment: @JAL And it never occurred to you to mention these emails in your answer?